# Kotlin: How can a child class use a parent's extension function in the super constructor call?

Tags: parent-child, subclass, extension-methods, kotlin

How can a child class use its parent's extension function in a lambda field?

Consider this parent class:

```
abstract class Parent(val field: Int.() -> Any) { 
    fun Int.print() = println(this) 
}
```

And this child:

```
class Child : Parent({
    print() // DOESN'T COMPILE
    this.print() // DOESN'T COMPILE

    5.print() // DOESN'T COMPILE

    val value = 5
    value.print() // DOESN'T COMPILE
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you cannot use `Parent`'s extension inside `Child` **super constructor call** argument is that its `Parent` part is not initialized yet at that point and thus cannot be used as *dispatch receiver* of the extension.

[Member extension functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#declaring-extensions-as-members) can use the eclosing class' members and this means that they need an instance of the class to be called with, and you cannot use the instance in its own constructor arguments.

Otherwise, you can use `Parent`'s extensions anywhere inside the `Child` members and in constructors (or `init` blocks), because super constructor is called before own constructors:

```
class Child : Parent {
    constructor(): super({}) {
        5.print()
    }

    fun f() {
        5.print()
    }

    val g: (Int) -> Unit = { it.print() }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example the lambda in question is not a field of `Parent` (strictly speaking), but a parameter to a function (class constructor).

The lambda is constructed (resolved) before any object, `Child` or `Parent`, is created. That's why methods can be resolved and the lambda is not in the scope of `Child`.

#### PS

The name of the topic suggests the following situation, but it compiles all right:

```
class Child : Parent({}) {
    val lambdaField: Int.() -> Any =  {
        print()
        this.print()
        5.print()
    }
}
```